# Null object when Injecting Repository with Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I can't get my Func to pass across successfully. I inject into the webapi in my startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(DbGlobals.DevDatabase,
    b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Services.Data.EF")));

services.AddTransient<Func<IMyDataContext>, Func<MyDataContext>>();
services.AddTransient(provider => new Func<IMyDataContext>(() => provider.GetService<IMyDataContext>()));
```

Then in my controller I have the following;

```
private ClientService _service;

public ClientController(Func<IMyDataContext> context)
{
    _service = new ClientService(context);
}
```

and the method in my service is;

```
private readonly Func<IMyDataContext> _contextFactory;

public ClientService(Func<IMyDataContext> contextFactory)
{
    _contextFactory = contextFactory;
}

public void AddClient(Client model, string userName)
{
    Func<Client> func = delegate
    {
        using (var context = _contextFactory())
        {
             ....
        }
    };

    return this.Execute(func);
}
```

Now from debugging if I inspect the controller injection I can see the Func is passed in and is at the service level 2. However when it comes to use it in the using statement on context = _contextFactory() it becomes null?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here please?

Comment: Just for clarification. is `context == null` or `_contextFactory == null` ?

Comment: context = null, i.e. calling _contextFactory()

Comment: I'm not sure why you use `Func<...>` for your DataContext but I would assume your function does not generate a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definitions are slightly wrong. You need to define that IDataContext and DataContext are related:

```
services.AddTransient<IDataContext, DataContext>();
```

Now the DI knows how to create the IDataContext. Now you method just needs to use the service provider to create it when the func is used:

```
services.AddTransient<Func<IMyDataContext>>(provider => () 
        => provider.GetService<IMyDataContext>());
```

Now, when your service is created, the DI will inject your Func<>